# How to make PATH variable exports on MacOSX persistent?

Tags: bash, shell, osx

I do

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy:8080 export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

on my Mac. Brew for instance relies on these settings. How can I make these settings stick between power cycles?

Is this the recommended way aka best practice?

```
echo "PATH=$PATH:/path/to/whtaever" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding entries to your `.bashrc` for settings to survive a powercycle (or just logout and login) is good practise, but both your examples have problems:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy:8080 export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

only sets and exports http_proxy on the first application:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://proxy:8080 export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy
$ echo $http_proxy
http://proxy:8080
$ echo $ALL_PROXY

$ export http_proxy=http://proxy:8080 export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy
$ echo $ALL_PROXY
http://proxy:8080
```

so put those on two separate lines in `.bashrc` in this order:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy:8080
export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

Appending to `.bashrc` using the `echo` command allows copy and paste as a one liner. It indiscriminatingly adds the entry and I rather would recommend to edit the file, search if there is already a definition, and replace it if there is (independent of doing such a thing for PATH or http_proxy). If you don't and there are multiple entries there is a good chance you update the wrong one, or just update `http_proxy` after the line with `ALL_PROXY` and wonder why the latter has the wrong value.

Comment: Thank you. There is no .bashrc, no .bash_profile and no .profile in my user folder. If I am not mistaken profile rules them all, system-wide, and bash_profile for login and bashrc only for the session in bash?

Comment: @AchmedDurangi No not exactly `~/.profile` is processed by bash if no `.bash_profile` is specified for **login shells only**. `~/.bashrc` also gets processed for non-login shells (e.g. if you open a terminal program on the commandline. See `man bash` section INVOCATION.